# Get keyValue from ListPreference

Tags: java, android, string, boolean, listpreference

Following problem:

`preferences.xml`:

```
    <ListPreference
        android:title="titel"
        android:summary="summary"
        android:key="remove_onclick"
        android:entries="@array/removeOnclick"
        android:entryValues="@array/removeOnclick_value"
        android:defaultValue="3"/>
```

My question is, **how I can get the Value (`1`, `2`, or `3`) to use it with an if-condition in my MainActivity.java**

```
    SharedPreferences sharedConfig = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String removeOnklick = sharedConfig.getString("remove_onclick", "3");
```

This does not work!

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be
>   cast to java.lang.String at
>   com.notification.app.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:14)

SettingsActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
 }
```

EDIT
`strings.xml`

```
<string-array name="removeOnclick">
    <item>Always</item>
    <item>Never</item>
    <item>Always ask</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="removeOnclick_value">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
```

And I also have 2 booleans which work perfectly.

```
    boolean playSound = sharedConfig.getBoolean("sound_on_create", false);
    boolean vibrate = sharedConfig.getBoolean("vibrate_on_create", false);
```

Update:

I just had to delete the cache and the memory...

Comment: What is the content of `arrays.xml`? (If that is the wrong question, where do you store the stuff for `@array`?)

Comment: In the strings.xml as a string-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, this line should be placed in MainActivity's onCreate method:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
```

And, to get the value from the ListPreference in SettingsActivity:

```
ListPreference pref = findPreference("remove_onclick");
String value = pref.getValue();
if (value.equals("3")){
    // do something here with value 3
}
```

If you want to get the value from MainActivity, call:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedConfig = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String removeOnklick = sharedConfig.getString("remove_onclick", "3");
    if(removeOnklick.equals("1"){
           // do something here with value 1
   }
```

Comment: I can't write `String removeOnklick = sharedConfig.getString` If I do this, and start the Settings it crashes.

Comment: @Landei00, Try to clear the app's data before you launch the app.

Answer (score -1):

try using getBaseContext():

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()) ;
```

and try this

```
if(removeonklick == "3")
{}
```

Comment: You can [edit] your answer to change the `removeonklick` line (by pressing the greyed-out edit below - or clicking on the [edit] in this comment).

Comment: `this` is appropriate inside of an Activity to get the preferences. Also, using `==` is the wrong way to compare `String` values in Java